# Colored progressbar

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar

I was using a program made in C# and came across these progress bars, one of which is blue.

Here's a picture of the progress bars in question:

[image: http://imgur.com/xAwA4]

The forecolor property obviously doesn't do anything, so does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the color?

Comment: if yes then possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032996/c-sharp-progress-bar-change-color

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a meter-style progress bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671366/how-can-i-use-a-meter-style-progress-bar)

Comment: Do you mean in a Wiforms application or a WPF one? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Visual styles as Habib suggested will work, But if you application relies on visual styles to look nicer, You will have to use a custom progress bar.

[Color Progress Bar - CodeProdject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6905/Color-ProgressBar)

TerrariViewer uses Wpf as I understand, and if your willing to use that, this is a possibility

[Progressbar foreground color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734814/wpf-progressbar-foreground-color)

Answer (score 8):

If its a winform application then do the following step

In `Program.cs` comment out the line

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

In code behind:

```
ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
```

Comment: However TerrariViewer (The application pictured) I belive uses custom progress bars, as It still retains visual Styles