# C# Change Marquee colour on Progress Bar windows application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, progress-bar, marquee

I have a application that will have a marquee progress bar but the color of the marquee is green, however the fore color is set to blue. How can i change the color of the marquee that's runs? I'm using a progress bar control and developing in C# on a windows form application.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show a Marquee, you have to have have visual styles *enabled*.

Changing the color of a Progress Bar is only observed if you have Visual Styles *disabled*.

See the StackOverflow questions : [C# progress bar change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032996/c-sharp-progress-bar-change-color) 
and
[Windows Forms ProgressBar: Easiest way to start/stop marquee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee)